# Weird fonts and no type 1

Tags: linux-mint, fonts

I can't understand why I can't see type 1 fonts anymore on some apps and on Desktop.

I made some upgrade on my Linux Mint, but I can't find a reason. I'll explain better:

I installed these pachages:

- pangox-compat
- libxml2
- libxml2.i686
- glibc
- glibc.i686
- libstdc++
- libstdc++.i686
- libjpeg-turbo
- libjpeg-turbo.i686
- beecrypt.i686
- beecrypt-devel.i686
- Canon cndrvcups-common_3.40-1_amd64.deb
- Canon cndrvcups-ufr2-uk_3.10-1_amd64.deb

Morevoer the Canon package had a erroneous install guide, so I added some python packages, so **pip list** is now (I suspect a python problem) :

```
apt-xapian-index (0.45)
apturl (0.4.1ubuntu4)
argparse (1.2.1)
BeautifulSoup (3.2.1)
ccsm (0.9.11.3)
chardet (2.0.1)
colorama (0.2.5)
command-not-found (0.3)
compizconfig-python (0.9.11.3)
configglue (1.1.2)
configobj (4.7.2)
debtagshw (0.1)
defer (1.0.6)
dirspec (13.10)
dnspython (1.11.1)
duplicity (0.6.23)
feedparser (5.1.3)
html5lib (0.999)
httplib2 (0.8)
lockfile (0.8)
lxml (3.3.3)
Mako (0.9.1)
MarkupSafe (0.18)
matplotlib (1.3.1)
nemo-emblems (0.0.1)
numpy (1.8.2)
oauthlib (0.6.1)
oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1)
PAM (0.4.2)
paramiko (1.10.1)
pexpect (3.1)
Pillow (2.3.0)
pip (1.5.4)
piston-mini-client (0.7.5)
Pivy (0.5.0)
ply (3.4)
protobuf (2.5.0)
pycollada (0.4)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pycups (1.9.66)
pycurl (7.19.3)
pygobject (3.12.0)
pygpgme (0.3)
pyinotify (0.9.4)
pyOpenSSL (0.13)
pyparsing (2.0.1)
pyserial (2.6)
pysmbc (1.0.14.1)
python-apt (0.9.3.5ubuntu2)
python-dateutil (1.5)
python-debian (0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2)
python-xlib (0.14)
pytz (2012c)
pyxdg (0.25)
reportlab (3.0)
requests (2.2.1)
sessioninstaller (0.0.0)
setuptools (3.3)
six (1.5.2)
system-service (0.1.6)
Twisted-Core (13.2.0)
Twisted-Names (13.2.0)
Twisted-Web (13.2.0)
urllib3 (1.7.1)
uTidylib (0.2)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
zenmap (6.40)
zope.interface (4.0.5)
```

and my pip3 list is:

```
apt-clone (0.2.1)
Brlapi (0.6.1)
chardet (2.2.1)
colorama (0.2.5)
command-not-found (0.3)
defer (1.0.6)
dirspec (13.10)
html5lib (0.999)
httplib2 (0.8)
language-selector (0.1)
louis (2.5.3)
lxml (3.3.3)
nbconvert (4.2.0)
oauthlib (0.6.1)
oneconf (0.3.7.14.04.1)
pexpect (3.1)
Pillow (2.3.0)
pip (1.5.4)
piston-mini-client (0.7.5)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pycurl (7.19.3)
pyflakes (1.3.0)
Pygments (2.1.3)
pygobject (3.12.0)
PyICU (1.5)
python-apt (0.9.3.5ubuntu2)
python-debian (0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2)
pyxdg (0.25)
QtAwesome (0.3.3)
reportlab (3.0)
requests (2.2.1)
setuptools (3.3)
six (1.5.2)
Sphinx (1.4.8)
spyder (3.0.0)
thin-client-config-agent (0.8)
ubuntu-drivers-common (0.0.0)
ufw (0.34-rc-0ubuntu2)
unattended-upgrades (0.1)
urllib3 (1.7.1)
virtkey (0.63.0)
xkit (0.0.0)
```

For example now some programs display strange and empty chars, like on that image, where the title has a weird font and the text on the white background has a lot of empty space, something that looks like square brackets:

[image: schermata2.png]

Moreover it seems that GTK applications can't show type 1 fonts anymore:

[image: WeirdFonts.png]

In the end, I really don't know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I found on internet the solution, the problem is the **pango-graphite** package, removing it solved all!!!!